# "Contains" not reading from my text file C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
if (intBestNumberOfTries > intNumberOfTries)
{
    string searchFor = LoginForm.strLoginName;
    string line;
    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"NameList.txt"))
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(searchFor))
            {
                line.Remove(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
StreamWriter scoreboard = new StreamWriter(@"NameList.txt", true);
scoreboard.WriteLine(""[{0}] " + LoginForm.strLoginName + " scored: {1}", intBestNumberOfTries, intBestNumberOfTries);
scoreboard.Close();
```

My `Loginform.strLoginName;` comes from another programming file. After I run the program, it does not remove the whole line. Instead, it writes a new line.
`searchFor` is my login name into the program.

Comment: You're not writing anything to that file. You're only reading.

Comment: Is that a syntax error or typo in `WriteLine` at `""[{0}]`?

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done in the way you're **providing**. You need to rewrite the **file**.

> How ?

You have to read the file into memory structure, remove the line in memory and then put the contents **back** to the file (it's just **overwriting**).

If you handle a file which is large or very large you have to read it line by line and creating a temp file(as helper) and then just replace the original one.

However, if the file is large you can use an `asynchronous` operation in order to not block the current thread. `c#` **StreamReader** function provided a solution for this using [StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Now, for your problem, you should use `File.ReadAllLines` method which **returns** an array of strings.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("NameList.txt");
```

The last step is to `filter` this array.

```
string[] filteredLines = lines.Where(l => !line.Contains(searchFor)).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, that's why every string.method like [`String.Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) will return a new string. You have to assign this returned string to your variable. For example: `line = line.Remove(0)`. Although i think you want something completely different(`Remove(0)` will return an empty string). Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx) of the methods to see what they are doing.

If you want to remove this line from the file you have to rewrite it with the lines you want to keep::

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("NameList.txt");
string[] keepLines = Array.FindAll(allLines, line => !line.Contains(searchFor));
File.WriteAllLines("NameList.txt", keepLines);
```

or use LINQ (`ReadLines` uses a streaming approach):

```
var allLines = File.ReadLines("NameList.txt");
var keepLines = allLines.Where(line => !line.Contains(searchFor));
File.WriteAllLines("NameList.txt", keepLines.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as following , You need to overwrite

```
        string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader("NameList.txt"))
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains(searchFor))
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        File.Delete("NameList.txt");
        File.Move(tempFile, "NameList.txt");
```

You can also achieve this with `Linq`

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => l.Contains(searchFor));

File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);

File.Delete(fileName);
File.Move(tempFile, fileName);
```

If you are not deal with large files  , then you can get rid from Temp file

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, 
File.ReadLines(fileName).Where(l => !l.Contains(searchFor)).ToList());
```